# Javascript looking for internet path instead of folders path

Tags: javascript, import, path, gltf

I am trying to import a class from "Home\templates\Home\node_modules\three\examples\jsm\loaders\GLTFLoader.js"
but when i run the server there is an Error 404 saying that there is no such file at "http://localhost:8000/Home/templates/Home/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"

I know that it's not searching the file at the right location but i don't find how to find point to the file in the project folder.

THE JS CODE

```
import { GLTFLoader } from '/Home/templates/Home/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
```

THE ERROR

```
GET http://localhost:8000/Home/templates/Home/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Are you doing this in the browser? It can't access files directly, only URLs, which have to be located in the web root.

Comment: Yes I am... how can i put my file in the web root? I am using django.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Django. But you do it the same way you put any other file on the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `npm install` to add `three` to your current project

You currently seem to have `three` installed globally in your computer, because you are trying to access it with a leading `/`, representing the root of your file system. That is no good for using it in a JS project. For that, you must install it in your project.

Go inside your project folder.

Type

```
npm install three
```

Then reference the file like this:

```
import { GLTFLoader } from './node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
```

Here, `./node_modules` is the node_modules inside your project, not the global one in your computer's `Home` folder.

Comment: Three is installed in the project. 'Home' is the name of one of my django applications.

Comment: So from the Root of your project, what is the path of the files? Use "." to represent the root of your project, and specify the location of the file relative to that. I thought it would be as I showed above, but maybe it is different for you? Where is your project's node_modules, if not in the root of your project?

Comment: The root of my project is just before the Home folder so i did './Home/templates/Home/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js' but it's the same error that occurs.

Comment: Next copy the GLTFLoader.js from its original location, into the same folder as your Javascript or HTML, so that you can access it via the web server.

Comment: i tried removing three form the project the running the command in the root but still same error .

Comment: Just copy the GLTFLoader.js from its original location, into the same folder as your Javascript file. Then you should be able to import it as "./GLTFLoader.js"